# Show something in a finder window

Tags: window, applescript, show, finder

Ok, I am trying to make a script where you type something and a new finder window appears with  what you typed in it. Similar to spotlight search, but in a script.

```
set theFind to text returned of (display dialog "What do you want to find?" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2)
    tell application "Finder"
        reveal theFind
    end tell
```

Comment: The Finder cannot reveal text. Which is what you are asking it to do. You need to add some sort of search command to find a matching file etc. Then parse the result of the search so the Finder can reveal it. Can I suggest you do some reading on AppleScript before you go any further. Doing so will save you a lot of time in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s an AppKit method that does exactly what (I think) you’re asking for: `-[NSWorkspace showSearchResultsForQueryString:]`, which means you can use it using AppleScriptObjC.  So, in AppleScript Editor, File > New from Template > Cocoa-AppleScript Applet, then:

```
property NSWorkspace : class "NSWorkspace"
NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()'s showSearchResultsForQueryString_(theFind)
```

Alternatively, you could skip AppleScriptObjC and use the hidden Finder command that that method uses:

```
tell application "Finder" to «event aevtspot» theFind
```